# StackOverflowError during Groovy compile

Tags: java, generics, compiler-construction, groovy, gradle

This has really been tormenting me.

I am compiling a Java/Groovy project using Gradle.  During the :compileGroovy task I am getting a StackOverflowError.

The stacktrace looks like this:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Could not call GroovyCompile.compile() on task ':compileGroovy'
    at org.gradle.util.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:219)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:212)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:201)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:527)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:510)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
    ... 53 more
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.HashMap.containsKey(HashMap.java:434)
    at java.util.HashSet.contains(HashSet.java:201)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.GenericsType.genericsBounds(GenericsType.java:114)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.GenericsType.genericsBounds(GenericsType.java:92)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.GenericsType.toString(GenericsType.java:73)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.GenericsType.genericsBounds(GenericsType.java:118)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.GenericsType.genericsBounds(GenericsType.java:92)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.GenericsType.toString(GenericsType.java:73)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.GenericsType.genericsBounds(GenericsType.java:118)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.GenericsType.genericsBounds(GenericsType.java:92)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.GenericsType.toString(GenericsType.java:73)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.GenericsType.genericsBounds(GenericsType.java:118)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.GenericsType.genericsBounds(GenericsType.java:92)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.GenericsType.toString(GenericsType.java:73)
```

I am using:
gradle:1.8
groovy:2.1.1

I have tried putting breakpoints inside the GenericsType class, but for some reason it's not stopping there.

My build.gradle looks like this:

```
apply plugin: "java"
apply plugin: "idea"
apply plugin: "groovy"
apply plugin: "maven"
apply plugin: "application"

def organizationId    = "sevenlights"

def projectSourceCompatibility = "1.6"
def projectTargetCompatibility = "1.6"

sourceCompatibility = projectSourceCompatibility
targetCompatibility = projectTargetCompatibility

version       = "1.0"
group         = "com.sevenlights"
description   = "7lights"

def mavenArtifactId        = "7lights"
def slf4jVersion           = "1.6.4"
def groovyVersion          = "2.1.1"
def springFrameworkVersion = "3.0.5.RELEASE"
def grailsVersion          = "2.2.2"
def gormVersion            = "1.3.7"
def junitVersion           = "4.11"

repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()

        maven { url "http://repo.grails.org/grails/core/" }
        maven { url "http://repository.codehaus.org" }
        maven { url "http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org" }
}

dependencies {
        compile ("org.slf4j:slf4j-api:${slf4jVersion}",
                 "org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:${slf4jVersion}",
                 "log4j:log4j:1.2.14",
                 "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:${groovyVersion}",
                 "org.grails:grails-gorm:${gormVersion}",
                 "org.grails:grails-core:${grailsVersion}",
                 "org.grails:grails-spring:${grailsVersion}",
                 "org.grails:grails-bootstrap:${grailsVersion}",
                 'com.h2database:h2:1.3.170',
                 "org.springframework:spring-context:${springFrameworkVersion}",
                 "org.springframework:spring-core:${springFrameworkVersion}",
                 "org.springframework:spring-context-support:${springFrameworkVersion}",
                 "org.springframework:spring-orm:${springFrameworkVersion}",
                 "org.springframework:spring-aop:${springFrameworkVersion}",
                 "org.springframework:spring-core:${springFrameworkVersion}",
                 "mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.22",
                 "joda-time:joda-time:2.2",
                 "com.google.code.gson:gson:1.7.1",
                 "org.jsoup:jsoup:1.7.2",
                 "org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup:tagsoup:1.2",
                 "org.grails:grails-test:1.3.6",
                 "org.jadira.usertype:usertype.jodatime:1.9"
        )

        compile("org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.7-SNAPSHOT") {
            exclude group: "org.codehaus.groovy", module:'groovy'
        }

        compile("org.springframework.uaa:org.springframework.uaa.client:1.0.3.RELEASE") {
                exclude group: "org.springframework.roo.wrapping", module:'*'
        }

        testCompile(
                "junit:junit:${junitVersion}",
                "org.easymock:easymock:3.2",
                "org.jmock:jmock:2.6.0",
                "org.jmock:jmock-junit4:2.6.0",
                "org.jmock:jmock-legacy:2.6.0",
                "cglib:cglib-nodep:2.1_3",
                "org.objenesis:objenesis:1.0",
                "org.hamcrest:hamcrest-integration:1.3",
                "org.mockito:mockito-all:1.8.4",
                "com.cyrusinnovation:mockito-groovy-support:1.2",
                "org.jmock:jmock-junit4:2.6.0",
                "org.spockframework:spock-core:0.7-groovy-2.0"
        )
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper, description: 'Generates the Gradle wrapper.') {
        gradleVersion = '1.6'
        jarFile = 'wrapper/wrapper.jar'
}

task myJar(type: Jar)

task copyToLib(type: Copy) {
    into "$buildDir/libs"
    from configurations.default
//    from configurations.default.allArtifactFiles
}

artifacts {
    archives myJar
}
```

My full dependency tree looks like this:

```
compile - Compile classpath for source set 'main'.
+--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.6.4
+--- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.6.4
|    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.6.4
|    \--- log4j:log4j:1.2.16
+--- log4j:log4j:1.2.14 -> 1.2.16
+--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.1.1
+--- org.grails:grails-gorm:1.3.7
|    +--- commons-lang:commons-lang:2.4 -> 2.6
|    +--- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:3.3.1.GA
|    |    +--- antlr:antlr:2.7.6
|    |    +--- commons-collections:commons-collections:3.1 -> 3.2.1
|    |    +--- dom4j:dom4j:1.6.1
|    |    |    \--- xml-apis:xml-apis:1.0.b2 -> 1.3.04
|    |    +--- javax.transaction:jta:1.1
|    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.5.2 -> 1.6.4
|    +--- org.grails:grails-core:1.3.7 -> 2.2.2
|    |    +--- commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2.1
|    |    +--- commons-io:commons-io:2.1
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-context:3.1.4.RELEASE
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:3.1.4.RELEASE
|    |    |    |    +--- aopalliance:aopalliance:1.0
|    |    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-asm:3.1.4.RELEASE
|    |    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:3.1.4.RELEASE
|    |    |    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:3.1.4.RELEASE
|    |    |    |    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-asm:3.1.4.RELEASE
|    |    |    |    |         \--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1
|    |    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:3.1.4.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:3.1.4.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:3.1.4.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-expression:3.1.4.RELEASE
|    |    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:3.1.4.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-asm:3.1.4.RELEASE
|    |    +--- com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap:concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru:1.3.1
|    |    +--- oro:oro:2.0.8
|    |    +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.0.8 -> 2.1.1
|    |    +--- xalan:serializer:2.7.1
|    |    +--- org.grails:grails:2.2.2
|    |    |    +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.0.8 -> 2.1.1
|    |    |    +--- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.6.2
|    |    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.6.2 -> 1.6.4
|    |    |    +--- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.0.1
|    |    |    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.6.2 -> 1.6.4
|    |    |    \--- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:1.0.1.Final
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:3.1.4.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-jms:3.1.4.RELEASE
|    |    |    +--- aopalliance:aopalliance:1.0
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:3.1.4.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:3.1.4.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-context:3.1.4.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:3.1.4.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-tx:3.1.4.RELEASE
|    |    |         +--- aopalliance:aopalliance:1.0
|    |    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:3.1.4.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:3.1.4.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-context:3.1.4.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |         \--- org.springframework:spring-core:3.1.4.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-tx:3.1.4.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.0.1
|    |    +--- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.6.10
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-aspects:3.1.4.RELEASE
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:3.1.4.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-context:3.1.4.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-context-support:3.1.4.RELEASE
|    |    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:3.1.4.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-context:3.1.4.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |         \--- org.springframework:spring-core:3.1.4.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.6.2 -> 1.6.4
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-expression:3.1.4.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-asm:3.1.4.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-context-support:3.1.4.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.grails:grails-bootstrap:2.2.2
|    |    |    +--- jline:jline:1.0
|    |    |    +--- org.fusesource.jansi:jansi:1.2.1
|    |    |    +--- org.apache.ant:ant:1.8.2
|    |    |    |    \--- org.apache.ant:ant-launcher:1.8.2
|    |    |    +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.0.8 -> 2.1.1
|    |    |    +--- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.6.2 (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.apache.ant:ant-launcher:1.8.2
|    |    |    +--- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.0.1
|    |    |    +--- org.apache.ivy:ivy:2.2.0
|    |    |    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.6.2 -> 1.6.4
|    |    |    +--- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:1.0.1.Final
|    |    |    +--- org.apache.ant:ant-trax:1.7.1
|    |    |    |    \--- org.apache.ant:ant:1.7.1 -> 1.8.2 (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.apache.ant:ant-junit:1.8.2
|    |    |    |    +--- org.apache.ant:ant:1.8.2 (*)
|    |    |    |    \--- junit:junit:3.8.2 -> 4.8.1
|    |    |    +--- net.java.dev.jna:jna:3.2.3
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:3.1.4.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    \--- org.codehaus.gant:gant_groovy1.8:1.9.6
|    |    |         +--- org.apache.ant:ant:1.8.2 (*)
|    |    |         \--- commons-cli:commons-cli:1.2
|    |    +--- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.6.10
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:3.1.4.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-web:3.1.4.RELEASE
|    |    |    +--- aopalliance:aopalliance:1.0
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:3.1.4.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:3.1.4.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-context:3.1.4.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:3.1.4.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-test:3.1.4.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.6.2 (*)
|    |    +--- asm:asm:3.1
|    |    +--- cglib:cglib:2.2
|    |    |    \--- asm:asm:3.1
|    |    +--- aopalliance:aopalliance:1.0
|    |    +--- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:1.0.1.Final
|    |    +--- commons-validator:commons-validator:1.3.1
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:3.1.4.RELEASE (*)
|    |    \--- commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:3.0.5.RELEASE -> 3.1.4.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:3.0.5.RELEASE -> 3.1.4.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-context:3.0.5.RELEASE -> 3.1.4.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-context-support:3.0.5.RELEASE -> 3.1.4.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:3.0.5.RELEASE -> 3.1.4.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-expression:3.0.5.RELEASE -> 3.1.4.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-instrument:3.0.5.RELEASE
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:3.0.5.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:3.0.5.RELEASE -> 3.1.4.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:3.0.5.RELEASE -> 3.1.4.RELEASE (*)
|    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-tx:3.0.5.RELEASE -> 3.1.4.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-orm:3.0.5.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:3.0.5.RELEASE -> 3.1.4.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:3.0.5.RELEASE -> 3.1.4.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:3.0.5.RELEASE (*)
|    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-tx:3.0.5.RELEASE -> 3.1.4.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-oxm:3.0.5.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:3.0.5.RELEASE -> 3.1.4.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-context:3.0.5.RELEASE -> 3.1.4.RELEASE (*)
|    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:3.0.5.RELEASE -> 3.1.4.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-tx:3.0.5.RELEASE -> 3.1.4.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.hibernate:ejb3-persistence:1.0.2.GA
|    +--- org.hibernate:hibernate-annotations:3.4.0.GA
|    |    +--- org.hibernate:ejb3-persistence:1.0.2.GA
|    |    +--- org.hibernate:hibernate-commons-annotations:3.1.0.GA
|    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.4.2 -> 1.6.4
|    |    +--- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:3.3.0.SP1 -> 3.3.1.GA (*)
|    |    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.4.2 -> 1.6.4
|    |    \--- dom4j:dom4j:1.6.1 (*)
|    +--- org.hibernate:hibernate-commons-annotations:3.1.0.GA (*)
|    +--- javassist:javassist:3.11.0.GA
|    +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:1.7.8 -> 2.1.1
|    +--- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.5.8 -> 1.6.2 (*)
|    +--- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:1.5.8
|    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.5.8 -> 1.6.4
|    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.5.8 -> 1.6.4
+--- org.grails:grails-core:2.2.2 (*)
+--- org.grails:grails-spring:2.2.2
|    +--- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.0.1
|    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.6.2 -> 1.6.4
|    +--- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:1.0.1.Final
|    +--- org.grails:grails-bootstrap:2.2.2 (*)
|    +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.0.8 -> 2.1.1
|    +--- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.6.2 (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-web:3.1.4.RELEASE (*)
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-tx:3.1.4.RELEASE (*)
+--- org.grails:grails-bootstrap:2.2.2 (*)
+--- com.h2database:h2:1.3.170
+--- org.springframework:spring-context:3.0.5.RELEASE -> 3.1.4.RELEASE (*)
+--- org.springframework:spring-core:3.0.5.RELEASE -> 3.1.4.RELEASE (*)
+--- org.springframework:spring-context-support:3.0.5.RELEASE -> 3.1.4.RELEASE (*)
+--- org.springframework:spring-orm:3.0.5.RELEASE (*)
+--- org.springframework:spring-aop:3.0.5.RELEASE -> 3.1.4.RELEASE (*)
+--- mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.22
+--- joda-time:joda-time:2.2
+--- com.google.code.gson:gson:1.7.1
+--- org.jsoup:jsoup:1.7.2
+--- org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup:tagsoup:1.2
+--- org.grails:grails-test:1.3.6
|    +--- commons-lang:commons-lang:2.4 -> 2.6
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-test:3.0.5.RELEASE -> 3.1.4.RELEASE
|    +--- junit:junit:4.8.1
|    +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:1.7.5 -> 2.1.1
|    +--- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.5.8 -> 1.6.2 (*)
|    +--- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:1.5.8 (*)
|    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.5.8 -> 1.6.4
+--- org.jadira.usertype:usertype.jodatime:1.9
|    \--- org.jadira.usertype:usertype.spi:1.9
+--- org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.7-SNAPSHOT
|    +--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.2.1
|    |    +--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.2.1
|    |    +--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1
|    |    \--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.6
|    +--- net.sf.json-lib:json-lib:2.3
|    |    +--- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:1.8.0
|    |    |    \--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1
|    |    +--- commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2.1
|    |    +--- commons-lang:commons-lang:2.4 -> 2.6
|    |    +--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1
|    |    \--- net.sf.ezmorph:ezmorph:1.0.6
|    |         \--- commons-lang:commons-lang:2.3 -> 2.6
|    +--- net.sourceforge.nekohtml:nekohtml:1.9.16
|    |    \--- xerces:xercesImpl:2.9.1
|    |         \--- xml-apis:xml-apis:1.3.04
|    \--- xml-resolver:xml-resolver:1.2
\--- org.springframework.uaa:org.springframework.uaa.client:1.0.3.RELEASE
```

Any help would very much be appreciated.

Comment: Well what does your script look like?

Comment: Are you referring to the gradle script?  Or the groovy script(s).  I can post the gradle script.  Alas there are dozens of groovy scripts.

Comment: Since it's Gradle you're compiling, yes, I was referring to that one. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a Groovy compiler bug. I recommend to try with a more recent Groovy version (`2.1.7` or `2.2.0-beta-2`).

Comment: Cheers, will give it a try.

Comment: Awesome.  Problem was fixed upgrading to groovy 2.1.7.  Thanks.